setup Ida/x64dbg
I have a 64-bit app disassembled with Ida 9.0.
I would like to attach x64dbg to it as a plugging so that it is recognized as a debugger in Ida.
Apparently, copying the plugging (x64dbgida.py) is not enough, How to configure Ida/.cfg?
Thanks

